# Label overlaps MaterialUI numeric Text Input Field value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this Material UI Text Input Field

```
<TextField
  label="Numeric"
  inputProps={{ inputMode: "numeric", pattern: "[0-9]+" }}
  type="number"
  variant="standard"
/>
```

When I type the letter "e" in the Text Input Field:

1. Is taking the letter "e" as a valid value I can type within the Text Input Field
2. The label overlaps the value

[image: Regular numeric value]

[image: Label overlaps the value]

Reproduce error: https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-demo-material-ui-forked-m14u7i?file=/demo.js

Comment: provide minimum reproduction of problem.

Comment: e is allowed in input type number

Comment: you should try preventing user from pressing 'e' in input type number

Comment: I checked in Material UI also there is this kind of issue. I think they have to set this issue.
I like your question brother .

Answer (score 0):

e is allowed because you can specify large numbers with it. you can prevent any character by regex. this is my solution to prevent user to type e

```
  function preventNonNumericalInput(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = typeof e.which == 'undefined' ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode); 
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[0-9\b]+$/);
    if ( !pattern.test(charStr)) e.preventDefault();
  }
```

you can add this function to onkeypress

```
    onKeyPress={e => preventNonNumericalInput(e)}
```